# Caching magento 2 (with CDN)

Tags: magento2, varnish, cdn, caching

On a local server I have a test-instance of Magento 2, by running a new build on that server and then rsyncing the code to the production, I switch to a new without downtime.

Recently I have added a CDN using GCS. I sync my files through `gsutil rsync` and `gsutil cp` (cp allows for compression). However, this, combined with caching results in some errors with caching. After I deploy a new instance of my site to production, cache has not been generated and will not be synced to my CDN.

How does caching work with CDN's? Am I required something like Fastly?

The same goes for merged JS files. It seems they are generated on the fly / dynamically. Hence they won't be present on my CDN